# Plotting log-scaled histograms in in plotly in R; display original values in tooltip box

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I am generating histograms using the `plotly` package in R to interactively inspect the distribution. In some cases, I have to apply a logarithmic function to make the plot easier to interpret. However, and as you would expect, when using `plotly`, the log-scaled value is presented in the tooltip box. What I would like to achieve is for the original values to be placed in the tooltip box instead of the log scale values.

Here is some example data and code:-

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(
  sex=factor(rep(c("F", "M"), each=200)),
  weight=round(c(rnorm(200, mean=55, sd=5),
                 rnorm(200, mean=65, sd=5)))
)


p <- ggplot(df, aes(x=weight)) + 
  geom_histogram()+
  scale_x_log10()


ggplotly(p)
```

Which gives you this outcome:-

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `paste` your `weight` in `ggplot(aes(text = ))`, and only include `text` and `y` in `ggplotly(tooltip = c("y", "text"))`.

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = weight, text = paste("Weight:", weight))) + 
  geom_histogram() +
  scale_x_log10()

ggplotly(p, tooltip = c("y", "text"))
```

[image: ggplotly]